# What is the difference between Application["Key"] and Application.Contents["Key"]?

Tags: c#, asp.net

`Application["temp"] = 8;` should set the value `8` to the key `temp`.

However, so does `Application.Contents["temp"] = 8;`

So what are the differences between these two?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Contents property is the default for Application, so when you use:

```
Application["temp"] = 8;
```

under the hood, the above code will be changed to call `Application.Contents["temp"] = 8`.

EDIT: I've just used Reflector and as Greg pointed out, the Contents property just returns a reference the current `HttpApplicationState` object. Not sure if my answer is strictly correct in this case - can someone verify this?

EDIT: OK, I found out that when you call `Application["temp"] = 8;` or `Application.Contents["temp"] = 8;` it actually call HttpApplicationState.Item. Check out this IL:

```
.method family hidebysig instance void Page_Load(object sender, class [mscorlib]System.EventArgs e) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldarg.0 
    L_0002: call instance class [System.Web]System.Web.HttpApplicationState [System.Web]System.Web.UI.Page::get_Application()
    L_0007: ldstr "Key"
    L_000c: ldc.i4.8 
    L_000d: box int32
    L_0012: callvirt instance void [System.Web]System.Web.HttpApplicationState::set_Item(string, object)
    L_0017: nop 
    L_0018: ldarg.0 
    L_0019: call instance class [System.Web]System.Web.HttpApplicationState [System.Web]System.Web.UI.Page::get_Application()
    L_001e: callvirt instance class [System.Web]System.Web.HttpApplicationState [System.Web]System.Web.HttpApplicationState::get_Contents()
    L_0023: ldstr "Key"
    L_0028: ldc.i4.8 
    L_0029: box int32
    L_002e: callvirt instance void [System.Web]System.Web.HttpApplicationState::set_Item(string, object)
    L_0033: nop 
    L_0034: ret 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of the "Contents" property is just to return a [reference to the HttpApplicationState object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate.contents.aspx).

It just returns `this`, so you could in theory do `Application.Contents.Contents.Contents.Contents["temp"] = 8;` and it would do the same thing.

Just use `Application["temp"] = 8;`.

Comment: The next question is "what use is this, really?"

Comment: Easy indexing.  I'm guessing they just wanted to make it look and feel just like Session.